# ASP.NET JS file does not update latest on SOME clients

Tags: javascript, .net, http, caching, model-view-controller

I am not really sure how to fully explain this problem. There has been this ongoing issue where SOME clients web browsers are not able to get the latest JS file for my website no matter what they do. Mind you, everything works fine when I visit the webpage from my workstation, but for others the js files are old versions.

Things we have tried:
-Appending a random parameter to the end of the js file `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/Main/main.js?319"> </script>`
-Force-refreshing the cache (Ctrl-F5)
-Setting Internet Options browsing history to "Everytime I visit a webpage"
-Clearing all browser data (IE, Chrome, Edge)

What is getting me is this doesn't happen to everyone, and it doesn't happen all the time. Only occasionally and only to some users and the issue always eventually resolves itself within a day or two. Whats going on here?

Website is an ASP.NET MVC application running on IIS8 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: you could try renaming the js file

Comment: That does work as a temp solution, but I cannot rename the file each time it changes, else I would need to update all references to that file every time it changes

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a silver bullet for you on this but my application has the same issue. In my instance we have a third-party authentication system (specifically, Tivoli Access Manager) between our clients and our server. Our suspicion has always been that something in TAM is caching stuff invisibly to us, and despite of any settings we have in IIS or what have you.

In your environment do you have any proxies or middle tiers that could be performing caching on your app's behalf?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware. Though that helps point me in the right direction I think. I am not very familiar with IIS management, do you happen to know of any settings IIS could be using that could cause this?

Comment: Try this out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/07/09/iis7-how-to-enable-content-expiration/

If you set expire immediately that should help prevent it from being cached. Granted this is a global setting for your whole site so you'd lose whatever benefit you'd get from caching other content (images, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give it a shot